# How to insert element only once on resize via jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following action:

```
var mtarget = $('.headshots');
var mwin = $(window).width();
var singlephoto = '<div class="officers-group-shot"><img src="my-image.jpg" alt=""></div>';

if (mtarget.length) {
    $(window).on("resize", function () {
        if (mwin < 800) {
            $('.headshots').addClass('d-none');
            $(singlephoto).insertBefore('.headshots:first');
        } else {
            $('.headshots').removeClass('d-none');
        }
    }).resize();
```

It works as expected, only that it keeps processing the insertBefore code over and over when you drag the screen.

**How can I insertBefore only once, while the screen is less then 800px on either load or drag?**

thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just take that line out of the resize handler?

Comment: because the replacement process should occur if the window is loaded the first time, or if the user decides to resize their window afterwards.

Comment: I don't want to keep creating it if it already exist on stage.  That is my struggle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if you have already added the div and only do it if you don't find it.

```
if (mwin < 800) {
  var $addedDiv = $(".officers-group-shot");
  if ($addedDiv.length == 0) {
    $('.headshots').addClass('d-none');
    $(singlephoto).insertBefore('.headshots:first');
  }
}
```